# Integer.parseInt() statement shows array index out of bound error while taking command line input in java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, parseint

I was trying to take three command line arguments as input and do some basic maths operations, but the compiler is showing arrayindex out of bound error in lines having `Integer.parseInt()`.

```
public class testarray {
        
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    
        int i=0;
        int length,start,increment;
        /*trying to take 3  command line arguments */
        length=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int array[]=new int[length];
        start=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        increment=Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        if(args.length!=3) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        else
        {
            for( i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
                array[i]=start+(start+increment);
            }
            System.out.printf("%5d%8d\n","index", "value");
        
            for(i=0;i<=array.length;i++) {
                System.out.printf("%d%d\n",i,array[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that statement can not cause that exception. check the line again

Comment: Then you are probably reading out of the bounds of your array.

Comment: /*trying to take 3  command line arguments */ -> how are you trying that?

Comment: That appear, if you run the program with less than 3 arguments

Comment: The _compiler_ is showing an error? Are you sure it is not an exception happening at runtime?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you posted the actual stacktrace. Other than that, it's probably because you're **1.** not providing three arguments to your program or **2.** your program throws it here `for(i=0;i<=array.length;i++) {`

Comment: it was due to the ide and the System.out.printf("%5d%8d\n","index", "value") line.also i corrected the loop .thank u

Answer (score 2):

In last for loop in your program you have:

```
for(i=0; i <= array.length; i++)
```

It should be changed to

```
for(i=0; i < array.length; i++)
```

Also I would suggest to check if you pass the arguments the right way (especially when using IDE you have to pass them the way your IDE requires it), because if they are not read correctly it may cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in your program. I suggest you to firstly print content of arrays to check if they are correctly filled with data you desired to store in them just to make sure everything is done properly.

Comment: im using eclipse IDE.the command line arguments print just fine .is shows the  same error on Netbeans.

Comment: also when i pass 2 or any other no. of  command line arguments it works fine and prints the first part of if clause and prints "error".

Comment: sorry guys.. i turns out it was a problem related to IDE.and System.out.printf("%5d%8d\n","index", "value");
this line.now its works fine

Comment: Yes, but the line I mentioned will cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException too because in the last loop it will try to make use of array[length] when last index of your array is array[length - 1]. Sooner or later you need to change it too.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to take three command line arguments then :

array.length = 3 , where indexes run from 0 , 1 and 2.

In last for loop of your program you have :

for(i=0; i <= array.length; i++)

Now , for i = 3 we have 3 <= array.length as true and when you try to access

array[3] in your for loop exception is raised . In order to avoid it

change follow

for(i=0; i < array.length; i++)